# Passing dictionary to javascript function error

Tags: javascript, python, flask

i have a dictionary that pass from python(flask) and i want to passing it to javascript function when i click on link but i don't know why i can't passing it and it error like this.

`SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break`

This is my code.

python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2}
    return render_template('index.html', dictionary=dictionary )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction('{{ dictionary }}');">click</a> 


<script>

function myFunction(dictionary){
  ..........
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flask.jsonify` when passing dictionary to jinja template in API call (like ajax and ...) and use `{{ dictionary|safe }}` in JavaScript part of template (in both API calls and passing variable to template).

Comment: thank you for response, but i think  jsonify that use only for passing value from python to template right, it not render the template with the data.

Comment: Did you use ```{{ dictionary|safe }}``` ?